# Help using contour integration/any other method?

Tags: contour-integration, residue-calculus, complex-integration

Need help with $\int^{a}_{0} \frac{\sqrt{(a + b)^2 - (x + b)^2}}{1 + x^2}$, where both "$a$" and "$b$" are real and positive. I would really appreciate if step wise solution of this integral can be provided. If the range of integration were say from "$-a-2b$" to "$a$", I can use contour integration to get the answer. But in this particular case, I am struggling to find a suitable contour. Oh by the way, Mathematica doesn't solve this definite integral. Help needed. Many thanks.

Comment: I am surprised that *" Mathematica doesn't solve this definite integral"* since, even if ugly, the antiderivative seems to exist. Could you try it ?

Comment: Yes. The indefinite integral does exist. But to put in the limits, and simplify it to real is really a mess..... I was hoping there could be a smarter way to get the definite integral by choosing an appropriate contour